Parse sfdisk progress of moving data from python
From my python script, I'm running subprocess.Popen("sfdisk...) to move the partition with all data to the right. It works, but it can take several minutes, and I'm not getting any progress information from stdout/stderr pipes.
If I run the same command from terminal, there is progress displayed on the last row, like Moved 249856 from 249856 sectors (100%). and it's updating, but when I call it from python, I don't get this line at all. Example of output looks like:
b'...\nData move:\n  start sector: (from/to) 2048 / 16000000\n  sectors: 249856\n  step size: 1048576 bytes'
b'The partition table has been altered.\nCalling ioctl() to re-read partition table.'

Is here any way to force sfdisk to send progress even if run from python? Or is here something wrong with my code? Full code below:
read, write = os.pipe()
os.write(write, b"16000000")
os.close(write)
p = subprocess.Popen("/usr/sbin/sfdisk --move-data /dev/sda -N 1".split(" "),stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=read)
fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl.fcntl(p.stderr.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

while True:
    output = p.stdout.read()
    error = p.stderr.read()
    if output == '' and error == '' and p.poll() is not None:
        break
    if output:
        print(output.strip())
    if error:
        print(error.strip())


Try setting the buffersize parameter to Popen().

Usually, such cmd-line utilities display such progress information to the stderr stream. Confirm this true for the sfdisk util, and then see how to redirect stderr for your python code. Just an idea, I have no significant python experience. Good luck!

Finally, I have solved this by use pty.openpty(). Here is final code. Not my proudest piece of code, it's quite dodgy, but it works.
def sfdisk_update_partition(start=None, length=None, partition_number=None, print_output=False):
    global status
    global progress

    if not partition_number:
        raise Exception("partition_number not specified")

    progress = 0
    status = STATUS.STARTED

    master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()

    p = subprocess.Popen(f"/usr/sbin/sfdisk --move-data /dev/sda -N {partition_number}".split(" "), stdout=slave_fd, stderr=slave_fd, stdin=slave_fd, close_fds=True)
    if start and length:
        os.write(master_fd, f"{start}, {length}\n".encode())
    elif start:
        os.write(master_fd, f"{start}\n".encode())
    elif length:
        os.write(master_fd, f", {length}\n".encode())
    else:
        progress = 1
        status = STATUS.DONE

    while True:
        output = os.read(master_fd,1024).decode()
        if not output and p.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            if print_output:
                print(output)
            if "Do you want to write this to disk?" in output:
                os.write(master_fd, b"y\n")
            elif "Do you want to move partition data?" in output:
                os.write(master_fd, b"y\n")
            elif "Syncing disks" in output:
                break
            elif "sfdisk: start of the partition has not been moved; ignoring --move-data" in output:
                break
            elif "sfdisk: Use the --force flag to overrule all checks." in output:
                break
            else:
                r = re.search(r"Moved (.*?) from (.*?) sectors", output)
                if r:
                    status = STATUS.RUNNING
                    progress = float(r.groups()[0])/float(r.groups()[1])
    progress = 1
    status = STATUS.DONE
    os.close(master_fd)
    os.close(slave_fd)
    time.sleep(2)
    p.kill()
    time.sleep(1)


@tripleee, Indentation errors fixed. This is just draft, proof of concept, so I don't care that much about global variables. As I said, not my proudest piece of code, but I will clean it before final implementation.
